# Google beacon dashboard - NearBy notifications not showing app and only one device can see NearBy messages

Tags: android, google-beacon-platform

I'm trying to develop a simple no app use case for our beacon based project.

I've created a project and configured 3 beacons via Google Beacon Dashboard with proper https URLs (checked with Google provided Physical Web URL checker tool) and EN as language.

As a result the notifications do not show at any device at all and the beacon messages I configured can be manually searched by Nearby app only on my own device which I used to configure those beacons. No other device can see them even with manual search in Nearby app, while our project app and 3rd party app can see the beacons seamlessly.

Our beacons are iBeacons.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Though it does not solve your problem, maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210362/4499889) can help you.

You could change the iBeacon to Eddystone URL in order to broadcast the notification (though if I remember correctly it will only work for Android :( ).

One last thing: did you put your notifications in `Production Mode`? AND your links MUST be in HTTPS

[image]