# Can't see my registered beacon in google beacon platform

Tags: ibeacon, beacon, eddystone, google-beacon-platform, eddystone-url

I have got SENSORO beacon which I have configured using congif tool from Sensoro. Then I have created a project for beacon(Google API). Then I have registered the beacon using Beacon Tool from google, it got registered. But I am unable to see my beacon in Google Beacon Platform. I waited for almost 20 hrs but still not appearing.

BTW what is difference between Eddystone and Eddystone URL, because for a single beacon I was getting Eddystone(This got registered) and Eddystone URL(Still unregistered).

Have I missed any steps or it usually take more time ?

Comment: Working fine, just wait for 24 hrs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the difference between Eddystone and Eddystone URL:

- an Eddystone beacon contains a unique identifier which must be registered with the [Google Beacon dashboard](https://developers.google.com/beacons/dashboard/). You need your own app to handle the beacon.
- an EddyStone-URL beacon broadcasts a short https url. You don't need to register it with the [Google Beacon dashboard](https://developers.google.com/beacons/dashboard/), and more importantly, you don't need an application to deal with the beacon. Latest versions of Android and Chrome will natively display a notification to the user to suggest him to open the corresponding web page.